# How to insert a javascript object into sqlite database?

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite

I have a javascript object as :

```
service location : Object
   formatted_address:"Jharkhand, India"
   latitude : "23.6101808"
   longitude :"85.2799354"
```

How can I insert this `in a single column` as object in my sqlite database.

I want to receive this column value as an object in my response when I execute SELECT query on my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert it into JSON String and send it.

```
JSON.stringify({
  service_location: {
    formatted_address: "Jharkhand, India",
    latitude: "23.6101808",
    longitude: "85.2799354"
  }
});
```

This will be converted into:

```
{"service_location":{"formatted_address":"Jharkhand, India","latitude":"23.6101808","longitude":"85.2799354"}}
```

And this can be safely decoded using:

```
JSON.parse('{"service_location":{"formatted_address":"Jharkhand, India","latitude":"23.6101808","longitude":"85.2799354"}}');
```

Comment: yeah but when i will execute select query on this column I will receive an string but I want to receive an object.

Comment: @lakshay You should convert it into object by using `json_decode()` in PHP or `JSON.parse()` in JavaScript. Coz you cannot store anything other than string, while dealing with data from and to databases.